# Grid column width based on content not working

Tags: html, css, image, css-grid

I have the following layout defined using CSS grid, see the demo below:

```css
.blog-post {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(auto, max-content) 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: auto minmax(auto, max-content);
  background: #fff;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  grid-column: 2/-1;
  width: 100%;
}

.blog-post h1 {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.blog-post img {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2;
  height: 100%;
}

.blog-post p {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="blog-post-item" class="blog-post">
  <h1>Some amazing blogpost title about something super cool!</h1>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/44/3-4_ratio_mobile_wallpaper_example.jpg">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, repellendus natus! Corporis, architecto laboriosam natus doloremque corrupti sunt a incidunt! Eligendi soluta beatae neque reprehenderit ipsa perspiciatis architecto accusantium incidunt.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, repellendus natus! Corporis, architecto laboriosam natus doloremque corrupti sunt a incidunt! Eligendi soluta beatae neque reprehenderit ipsa perspiciatis architecto accusantium incidunt.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, repellendus natus! Corporis, architecto laboriosam natus doloremque corrupti sunt a incidunt! Eligendi soluta beatae neque reprehenderit ipsa perspiciatis architecto accusantium incidunt.
  </p>
</div>
```

But as you can see in the image below the image falls outside of the grid:

[image]

How do I fix this?

If more clarification or information is needed let me know so I can edit the question.

Comment: is the `img{height:100%;}` a must ?  Have you tried  `object-fit` property ?

Comment: yes the `img{height:100%}` is a must since it makes sure it looks nice in the total layout.
It tried `object-fit` but then the image is cut off or squished which is not desired. If i need to change the html for it to work i am open to it btw :)

Comment: if height 100% is a must, at one point the image will be as wide as the viewport and before that can let very little room for the text making it awful and difficult to read . You should somehow allow it to wrap below or on top of the text, mediaquerie will be required i guess.

Comment: yes you are correct but my style accounts for this issue. But this isnt relevant to the problem i am having though..

Comment: okay, add an image to your code, so it can reproduce your issue. here on the screenshot  the image is taller than the text aside ;)

Comment: added an image :) but just to be clear the image should have a height of 100% of the container regardless of the text. the text may be hidden if it is larger than the container space. thanks for taking the time to help :)

Comment: btw the blog-post div is inside of another grid if that is any help

Comment: I had a similar problem, but your question itself answered my question :D

Answer (score 0):

I just tried another image link and the style seems to be correct.
But try to look in developer tool in your browser maybe the style is overwritten.

and try to give the image tage a `max-width: 100%;` of the container

```css
.blog-post {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(auto, max-content) 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: auto minmax(auto, max-content);
  background: #fff;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  grid-column: 2/-1;
  width: 100%;
}

.blog-post h1 {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.blog-post img {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2;
  height: 100%;
}

.blog-post p {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="blog-post-item" class="blog-post">
  <h1>Some amazing blogpost title about something super cool!</h1>
  <img src="https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/stack-of-books-picture-id157482029?s=612x612">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, repellendus natus! Corporis, architecto laboriosam natus doloremque corrupti sunt a incidunt! Eligendi soluta beatae neque reprehenderit ipsa perspiciatis architecto accusantium incidunt.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, repellendus natus! Corporis, architecto laboriosam natus doloremque corrupti sunt a incidunt! Eligendi soluta beatae neque reprehenderit ipsa perspiciatis architecto accusantium incidunt.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, repellendus natus! Corporis, architecto laboriosam natus doloremque corrupti sunt a incidunt! Eligendi soluta beatae neque reprehenderit ipsa perspiciatis architecto accusantium incidunt.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I checked that the style doesnt get overwritten. And when using your image it still doesnt work.

Comment: Do you have a link for debugging ?

Comment: sorry i dont have a link

Answer (score 0):

Images behave bit differently in CSS Grids. They don't occupy the complete grid as mentioned.
One of the possible solution can be, Try to wrap that image inside a div & place that div accordingly. This should resolve the issue.

I have updated the html & css accordingly. Check this out [Image Placing in Grid](https://codepen.io/hemanthvhs/pen/wvzXaZO?editors=1100) for reference.

```css
*,*::before,*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  bpx-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: orangered;
}

.blog-post {`enter code here`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.blog-post h1 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.blog-post div {
  grid-column: 7 / 9;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

img {
  width: 50%;
}

.blog-post p {
  grid-column: 1 / 6
}
```

```html
<div id="blog-post-item" class="blog-post">
  <h1>Some amazing blogpost title about something super cool!</h1>
  <div>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d5/CSS3_logo_and_wordmark.svg/544px-CSS3_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png">
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, repellendus natus! Corporis, architecto laboriosam natus doloremque corrupti sunt a incidunt! Eligendi soluta beatae neque reprehenderit ipsa perspiciatis architecto accusantium incidunt.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, repellendus natus! Corporis, architecto laboriosam natus doloremque corrupti sunt a incidunt! Eligendi soluta beatae neque reprehenderit ipsa perspiciatis architecto accusantium incidunt.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, repellendus natus! Corporis, architecto laboriosam natus doloremque corrupti sunt a incidunt! Eligendi soluta beatae neque reprehenderit ipsa perspiciatis architecto accusantium incidunt.
  </p>
</div>
```